# Can someone explain what a butterfly is in regards to DSP?

Tags: fft, convolution

I often see the term "butterfly" in discussion and methods relating to DSP. What is a "Butterfly?"

Comment: The first Google result for "fft butterfly" [describes it pretty well](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Butterfly_diagram).

Comment: First port of call for definitive answers is (for me at least), here.

Comment: Have you tried [this](http://letmegooglethat.com/?q=butterfly+fft) ?

Comment: Late to the party and a dollar short.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wikipedia has this one covered:

> In the context of fast Fourier transform algorithms, a butterfly is a portion of the computation that combines the results of smaller discrete Fourier transforms (DFTs) into a larger DFT, or vice versa (breaking a larger DFT up into subtransforms). The name "butterfly" comes from the shape of the data-flow diagram in the radix-2 case, as described below.[1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Butterfly_diagram) The earliest occurrence in print of the term is thought to be in a 1969 MIT technical report.[2][3] The same structure can also be found in the Viterbi algorithm, used for finding the most likely sequence of hidden states.

([Source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Butterfly_diagram))

Comment: This should be a comment.